# iframe in XHTML Transitional not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, iframe, xhtml-transitional

So, basically what I'm trying to do is have a Chrome extension to properly render MathML expressions (I've tried the "MathJax for Chrome" extension, but it doesn't work for me).

My original plan was to just add a link to the MathJax code in the `head` node, but this doesn't work (I assume because it's added *after* the page is loaded).

My current plan is to replace each MathML object with an `iframe` that references the MathJax code and just includes the original MathML object. Since the `iframe`'s HTML is based on the original MathML element, I'm using the `srcdoc` attribute. Here's my current script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("math").each(function(index, obj) {
        // create an inline frame to replace the math element
        var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
        var html = '<html><head><script type="text/javascript" src="https://c328740.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"></script></head>';
        html += '<body>';
        // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419749/get-selected-elements-outer-html
        html += $(obj).clone().wrap('<p>').parent().html();
        html += '</body></html>';
        $(iframe).attr("srcdoc", html);
        iframe.textContent = "FOO";
        $(obj).replaceWith(iframe);
    });
});
```

This works for non-XHTML pages, like Mozilla's MathML "Torture Test", but for XHTML (even Transitional) I just get the `"FOO"` text.

Is there something else I need to do to get `iframe`s working for XHTML Transitional? Or is there a better way to achieve what I want?

Comment: MathJax should work in XHTML when added to the head even after the page is loaded.  We don't do a lot of testing in XHTML, though, so something may need fixing.  Can you give a complete example showing what you have tried?  The iframe approach should not be necessary, and will be very inefficient even if it works.

Comment: This was my original attempt: http://pastebin.com/Tc6npxuC

Answer (score 0):

Here is the issue:

- `srcdoc` was added to the iframe element as part of the [HTML5](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-html/2010Oct/0169.html), which is triggered by the HTML5 doctype
- XHTML Transitional does not use the HTML5 doctype

Use an encoded [data: URI](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2397.txt) plus an `object` element for backwards compatibility, as follows:

```
var newobj = $("<object/>", {"text":"FOO"});
var html = "<html><head></head><body><p>XHTML is the best</p></body></html>"
var xhtml = encodeURIComponent(html);
newobj.appendTo("body");
/* Add attribute values after appending to the DOM */
$(newobj).attr({data:'data:text/html;charset=utf-8;,'+xhtml, type:"text/html"})
```

**References**

- [jQuery API Documentation: Quick Element Construction](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2)
- [What's next in HTML, episode 2](http://blog.whatwg.org/whats-next-in-html-episode-2-sandbox)
- [HTML5 New Tags](http://www.felgall.com/html5v.htm)
- [The Object Tag](http://www.felgall.com/noiframe.htm)
- [Improved Object Fallback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cc304133#Fallback)
- [incorrect handling of fragment identifiers in data: URIs](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=123004)
- [data: Protocol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc848897)
- [IE11 Feature Request: Support for srcdoc and seamless attributes on iframe](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/793967/ie11-feature-request-support-for-srcdoc-and-seamless-attributes-on-iframe)
- [XHTML Transitional as text/xml](http://hsivonen.com/test/xhtml-suite/xhtml10-transitional.xml)
- [Layout Mode Test](http://vesa.piittinen.name/doctype/)